# c# grouping objects on windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

This is a very simple logic circuit diagram designer in c# windows forms.

#### Notes

- Has a `Gate` superclass
- `AndGate`, `OrGate`, etc.., `Compound` inherits from `Gate`
- Seperate classes for `Pin` and `Wire`
- Form has `Form1_Paint` event handler
- Form has `MouseClick`, `MouseDown` , `MouseUp`, `MouseMove` event handlers
- `Compound` = Group

I can add a gate like so.

[image: I can add a gate like so.]

[image]

And link the two using wires by clicking and dragging from first pin to other pin.

[image]

I can and need to select ONE gate

[image]

To be able to drag and move it

[image]

**Now this is the feature I'm stuck with.**

I want to be able to add a group like so.

[image]

Add the gates I want and end the group.

[image]

## Problem

- I want to be able to move the entire `Compound` object (all of its gates)
- I want it so that I can still select the individual gates (for instance, by selecting an input, i flick the `InputSource` from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.
- I want it so that I can still draw wires from one the gates inside a `Compound` to another `Gate` outside the `Compound`

---

Some things I tried to do but cannot get to work properly.

- `Bitmap` inside the `Compound` class.
- `Panel` inside the `Compound` class and add to windows form

Comment: I'm surprised that you're putting the effort to do this in winforms, which is an obsolete technology, when you could be doing this in WPF with 10% the amount of effort, time, and code. (and no flicker).

Comment: Can't be helped. It's a school thing.

Comment: if school is teaching you winforms, you'd rather quit school and learn proper technology on your own, from google.

Comment: It is supposed be a first year introductory course to c# and OOP programming.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: No wonder your nickname. You'll love working with .Net graphics once you stop using useless technology from 500 years ago and embrace the useful modern stuff. See XAML, UWP, WPF.

Comment: You could add a property to each object that indicates the group it belongs to and then, whenever you start dragging an object, you can test that property and move the other items with the same value in that property.

Comment: Stuck for two days and haven't thought of that. I'll try this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @HighCore Yeah winforms was a popular technology in 1515 and you should quit school. Great advice.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, Winforms is a good, stable technology that's realatively easy to use. WPF is a load of slow complicated crap. AT leas it's what i listen from everyone that uses both. Also, not being the latest propular hype is a good thing for people that do real work on applications people and companies use everyday.

Comment: @osiris My comment was a response to a comment from Federico Berasategui (named "HighCore" 7 years ago), and it was purely sarcastic. Thanks for staying polite :)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, I'm sorry. I was tired and didn't notice it. I was overly harsh and not very polite. From now on i will read a comment twice before thinking about responding to it.

Comment: @osiris And I'll stop posting sarcastic passive-aggressive comments!